# c#, VS Make a piece of code to appear in derived class method while overriding

Tags: c#, visual-studio, oop, polymorphism, overriding

Is there a way to make a piece of code to appear within method while overriding?
Just like this:

```
    public class BaseClass
    {
      public abstract void SomeMethod()
      {
         //here  want to place a piece of code which I want to use in derived class while overriding (for ex. try-catch block)
         try
         {
         }
         catch
         {
         }

      }
    }

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
   public override void SomeMethod()
   {
      //here I would like for try-catch block to appear like informing me that it is the snippet which makes using of that method is better in this case
   }
}
```

I don't want to run a code from the base class. I just want for the overrided method to appear pre-populated with some snippet from the base class like informing me that it is the snippet which makes using of that method is better in this case

For example, when I'm overriding method in Visual studio through IntelliSense, "throw new NotImplementedException();" text appears within the method. My aim is to show some other snippet instead.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Are you wanting VS to auto-populated overridden methods with the code in the base class method? Kinda beats the point of overriding.

Comment: Yes, something like this.

Comment: For example, when I'm overriding method in Visual studio through IntelliSense, "throw new NotImplementedException();" text appears within the method. My aim is to show some other snippet instead.

Comment: There's no built in way of doing this, as I can't imagine anybody actually wanting this behavior.

Comment: And yes, I understand that it doesn't fit to the point of overriding and almost sure it is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do what you are asking for, however there are two ways to do something similar.

The first is to declare a method inside your class containing the code - your method calls that one and then continues.

The second is to create an abstract class with an abstract method in it (or just a normal class with an empty method). Have a method in your abstract class that contains the code you want and inside it calls the abstract method.

Your new class needs to implement that abstract method but the other code will be called before and after the call to the abstract method.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think that should work. And as I already know it has a name of Template Method Pattern.